# ImageBrush ImageSource x:Bind TargetNullValue different than datatamplate

Tags: binding, uwp-xaml, imagebrush, targetnullvalue

So, I have a `ListView` that is `x:Bind` to a list and a `DataTemplate`.

The `DataTemplate` has an `Elipse` filled with an `ImageBrush`.

**Everything works as it should but:**

If an item in the list has a `Null` value for its string URL image property, the app crashes.

I have tried setting a `TargetNullValue` but my problem is that the `X:DataType` of the template is a class from an API, so I cant control it. I want to have an image as a default value in case the item has an image value of null.

In other words, if the item's image URL property is `Null`, I want `XAML` to load a predefined image from my `Assets` folder.

The problem is that because I have set my `DataType` as the class, anything I `x:Bind` to has to be within that class.

```
<Ellipse Width="40" Height="40">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{x:Bind IconUrl, Mode=OneWay,TargetNullValue=/Assets/NoAvatarIcon.png}"/>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

The above for example doesn't work for a `Null` string in `ImageSource` as the `Path` is set to the `Class`.

Right? Any workarounds?

Comment: Yes, x:Bind is a little rough on `null` values. You can easily solve it in the ViewModel (return the fallback value) , or in the View as below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FallbackValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.Binding#Windows_UI_Xaml_Data_Binding_FallbackValue) in Binding and x:Bind is different.

In Binding, FallbackValue is the value to use when the binding is unable to return a value.

> A binding uses FallbackValue for cases where the Path doesn't evaluate on the data source at all, or if attempting to set it on the source with a two-way binding throws an exception that's caught by the data binding engine. FallbackValue is also used if the source value is the dependency property sentinel value [`DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty#Windows_UI_Xaml_DependencyProperty_UnsetValue).

But in x:Bind, FallbackValue specifies a value to display when the source or path cannot be resolved. It can't work with DependencyProperty.UnsetValue.

For your scenario, you can use Converter to operate `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` just like following code.

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        object res;        
        res = (value == null ? false : true) ? string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()) ? null : new BitmapImage(new Uri(value.ToString())) : null;
        return res;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Usage in Xaml File

```
  <Page.Resources>
        <local:ImageConverter x:Key="cm" />
    </Page.Resources>
    <StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListView x:Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:HeadPhoto">
                    <Ellipse Width="40" Height="40">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{x:Bind PicUri,TargetNullValue=/Assets/pic.png,Converter={StaticResource cm }}" />
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Placeholder image effect.

[image]

Comment: In the class you use:
`if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))`
which if the value is `Null` throws an exception because a `Null` cannot be converted to string. I also want to ask what is the point if it still returns `Null`? I mean the value taken from the API when there is no image is `Null` so why do we check if its `Null` and then return the same thing ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: I have modify the logic.

Comment: The image Source will be set  by  the return value of converter method. But [`x:bing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) is not only a sample set value operation.